# Как получить значения свойств объекта

Tags: javascript, json

Есть строка JSON:

```
{"1":{"main_id":"2_0","amount_o_v":"3","title":"2","folder":"2","site":"2","status":"1","password":"2","text":"2"}}
```

Преобразовываю её в объект:

```
var list = JSON.parse(result);
```

Как получить значение `main_id`? Варианты `list.1.main_id` и `list.main_id[1]` не работают.

Answer (score 4):

Вы не можете работать через `list.1`, т.к. `1` - число. Но вы можете пойти другим путем через `list['1']`:

```js
var json = '{"1":{"main_id":"2_0","amount_o_v":"3","title":"2","folder":"2","site":"2","status":"1","password":"2","text":"2"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj['1'].main_id);
```

[Почитать про ассоциативные массивы](http://js-help.net/text/object/baz-polzovat-obekty/obj_as_mass.php).